# Copy column data from source(Input) excel and write to the destination excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a source excel which already has data. Now i want to fetch data from col1, col3 and col5 and write to destination excel from bottom to top(means header is somewhere in the middle of the dest. excel sheet and my data should be written from the row above and not below.) 
Currently, i could fetch data from col1 and store in a list and print it, but don't know how to save it to destination excel.

Here are two questions

1) How to fetch column data from col1, col4, col8 .. etc
2) How to print that data in another excel

Thanks in advance.

**Below is the code**

```
    try {
        //sample excel file
        FileInputStream fileIn = new     FileInputStream("D:/ExportSample.xlsm");


        //workbook
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn);

        //open sheet at 0
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);


         //search for column index containing string "REV No." in the row 0 (which is first row of a worksheet
        String columnWanted = "REV No.";
        Integer columnNo = null;
        //output all not null values to the list
        List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();

        Row firstRow = sheet.getRow(2);

        for(Cell cell:firstRow){
            if (cell.getStringCellValue().equals(columnWanted)){

                columnNo = cell.getColumnIndex();
            }
        }

        if (columnNo != null){
        for (Row row : sheet) {
           Cell c = row.getCell(columnNo);
          // final String[] array = cells.toArray(new String[cells.size()]);
           if (c == null || c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
              // Nothing in the cell in this row, skip it
           } else {
              cells.add(c);
           }
        }
        System.out.println("Column values : "+cells.toString());


        }else{
            System.out.println("could not find column " + columnWanted + " in first row of " + fileIn.toString());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Output** 
Column values : [REV No., RA00012A, RA00013A, RA00014A]

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) and trying some of the examples given there?

Comment: yes, but POI is row based, so i was unable to fetch specific columns and save them into another excel.

Comment: You just iterate through the rows in one file, fetching the values of the cells in a given column, then do the same on the new file writing them into that column. Just because the file format is row based not column based doesn't mean it's impossible to read by column, just that you have to turn your iteration round!